# Is it possible to Accessing the ggsci (Oracle GoldenGate) and modification of parameter file in dirprm from remote machine

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

We have a replicated database and want to add one more table to the replicated database. For that, we need to stop & start the golden gate process. As well as have to modify the parameter. All these things we have to do after login in to the Oracle Server.

Is it possible to access the ggsci and modify the parameter file (in dirprm) from a remote machine? Or in other words in place of performing all these steps manually. Is it possible to do all the above things by automation?

Thanks & Regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box in classic architecture.  You would need to customize and script that.

However, this feature is available in the Microservices architecture with RestAPI and AdminClient.